# Keeping a session in python while making HTTP requests

Tags: python, http, authentication

I need to write a python script that makes multiple HTTP requests to the same site.  Unless I'm wrong (and I may very well be) urllib reauthenticates for every request.  For reasons I won't go into I need to be able to authenticate once and then use that session for the rest of my requests.

I'm using python 2.3.4

Comment: Authentication is driven by the site.  If they ask for authentication (via  401 response), your client can provide it.  You can (sometimes) head this off.  Depends on the site's use of the Nonce.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to keep the authentication you need to reuse the cookie. I'm not sure if urllib2 is available in python 2.3.4 but here is an example on how to do it:

```
req1 = urllib2.Request(url1)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req1)
cookie = response.headers.get('Set-Cookie')

# Use the cookie is subsequent requests
req2 = urllib2.Request(url2)
req2.add_header('cookie', cookie)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req2)
```

Comment: python 2.3.4 does have urllib2.  Thanks

Comment: That's not so straightforward as you show it is. See RFC 6265, section *5.4 The Cookie Header*, when you find this statement *The user agent MUST use an algorithm equivalent to the following algorithm to compute the "cookie-string" from a cookie store and a request-uri:* with the following algorithm.

Answer (score 29):

Use [Requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) library. From http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects :

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across
>   requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the
>   Session instance.
>
> ```
> s = requests.session()
>
> s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
> r = s.get("http://httpbin.org/cookies")
>
> print r.text
> # '{"cookies": {"sessioncookie": "123456789"}}'
> ```

Comment: requests has serious memory leak problem: https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4601

Answer (score 16):

### Python 2

If this is cookie based authentication use [HTTPCookieProcessor](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#examples):

```
import cookielib, urllib2
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
r = opener.open("http://example.com/")
```

If this is HTTP authentication use [basic or digest AuthHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#examples):

```
import urllib2
# Create an OpenerDirector with support for Basic HTTP Authentication...
auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm='PDQ Application',
                          uri='https://mahler:8092/site-updates.py',
                          user='klem',
                          passwd='kadidd!ehopper')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
# ...and install it globally so it can be used with urlopen.
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/login.html')
```

... and use same opener for every request.

### Python 3

In Python3 urllib2 and cookielib were moved to [http.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#examples) and [http.cookiejar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#examples) respectively.

Comment: Can we manage session and basic auth together? For example using more handlers, i.e.: opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj), auth_handler) ??

Comment: @FabianoTarlao Sure you can. That's the beauty of python's urllib :-)

Comment: Thank you, I was going to update my comment but you anticipated me -- I have successfully tried and works like a charm.