# Using Python to get Google Apps log in

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I would like to download a file which is in a website that I should get google apps log in.
Is there any library in python that I could do it?

Thank you

Comment: HTTP authentication is commonly implemented using cookies. You may want to check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923296/keeping-a-session-in-python-while-making-http-requests) , as well as the [cookielib documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html). Or you may just use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

In App Engine you can use the [User Service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingusers) as an easy way to make sure that only logged-in people can access a particular URL of your app, including a file download URL.