# getSession() always creates a new session

Tags: java, session, web.xml, servlet-filters

We have SecurityFilter class in our application by implementing Filter and our doFilter method looks like this.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest sres, ServletResponse sreq,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        LOGGER.debug(Logger.buildLogMessage("Starting SecurityFilter.doFilter"));
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) sres;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) sreq;

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

We have the following entry in our web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.a.b.c.web.filter.SecurityFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

We have many REST calls to our application and all of them pass through this filter. The Java API documentation says, the request.getSession() returns a session if exists else it creates a new session. But in our application the request.getSession() always creates a new session for every REST call. What could be going wrong here ?

Comment: Start with the client and make sure it is sending a JSESSIONID cookie.

Comment: If the client doesn't send the session cookie as part of its requests, the server has no way to know which session the request belongs to, and it thus recreates one.

Comment: By maintaining session you are violating one of the basic constraints of REST architecture

Comment: @Anirudha that's not true.  The connection is stateless, not the session.

Comment: Sniff the request/response to see if the cookie is there for subsequent calls, like @Ted proposed.

Comment: @TedBigham The REST API consumer is a python script which polls(every 15m) from a different system. How to maintain a JSESSIONID cookie in this case ?

Comment: The python script would have to maintain state between invocations.  So this is really looking like a python question as opposed to a java one.  Fun.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923296/keeping-a-session-in-python-while-making-http-requests

Answer (score 0):

If your application settings are set to track JSESSIONID via cookie, the application will return the same session if you're making a request from the same browser, and a new session if you're making a request from a different browser. This is obviously because cookies live on a per-browser basis.