# New session always being created when using getSession()

Tags: java, session, cookies, session-cookies, jsessionid

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007445/getsession-always-creates-a-new-session), but that question is over 4 years old and doesn't have an accepted answer. I'll offer bounty from this question if it does not get an answer.

In my J2EE web application, I have a `Filter` called `AlwaysCreateSessionFilter`. Here is my `doFilter` method:

```
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) {
    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

And in this war's `web.xml`, I have:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

The browser always correctly includes a `JSESSIONID` cookie with the value from the server's most recent response (provided in the response's `Set-Cookie` header). But the problem is that the server always provides a *brand new* value for `JSESSIONID` in the `Set-Cookie` header, not the same one provided with the request. So the server is creating a new session on each request.

I have set a breakpoint in the `doFilter` method, and can confirm that `request.getSession(false)` returns a valid session with the correct id that corresponds to the value of the `JSESSIONID` cookie being provided with the request. It's just that, when the server responds, it always has that `Set-Cookie` header set to a brand new JSESSIONID, and I can't figure out what is doing it.

Here is crude diagram to illustrate what is happening:

[image: Problem workflow]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you use other web tools as f5 or cloudeflare which can effect cookie?

Comment: No, not to my knowledge. But as I stated, the cookie is definitely making it to the server. I can evaluate the `HttpServletRequest` using `request.getCookies()` and see a cookie named `JSESSIONID` with a value that corresponds to the most recent value provided by the server (via the `Set-Cookie` header in the response). @user7294900 Is that not an accurate way to tell that nothing funky is happening with the cookie?

Comment: Cookie is saved in same path of following request?

Comment: Added a diagram to address your question