# Python - urllib2 How to open other url directed from one url

Tags: python, urllib2

So say we needed to use authentication before we can actually access the web then:

```
import urllib2, base64
authenip = "10.203.10.12" #What ever the authenication ip is....
req = urllib2.Request("http://" + authenip)
base64string = base64.encodestring("username:password").replace("\n", "")
req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
requested = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Alright but from here since we have now logged in, how do we go to a website?

Comment: after login, does server return you such like a sesssion id ?

Comment: Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923296/keeping-a-session-in-python-while-making-http-requests