# flask query works on browser but not on terminal?

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

so i am trying to allow the user to only retrieve 50 queries at a time from the database using a flask server. Here is my logic

server.py

```
@app.route('/getEmployees/<userid>')
def all(userid):
    # Allow the user to specify an offset via querystring
    offset = request.args.get('offset')

    # Allow user to specify limit but default to 50
    limit = request.args.get('limit', 50)

    if offset is None:
        # Look in the session and default to 0 if not defined
        offset = session.get('offset', 0)


    g.db = connect_db()
    cur = g.db.execute('select * from employees limit %d offset %d' % (limit, int(offset)))
    entry=[dict(emp_no=row[0],birth_date=row[1],first_name=row[2],last_name=row[3],gender=row[4],hire_date=row[5]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    g.db.close()

    session['offset']= offset + limit;
    return str(entry)
```

now  gooduser.py

```
from timeit import default_timer
import urllib2


userid='gooduser'

start=default_timer()

req = urllib2.Request('http://0.0.0.0:5000/getEmployees/'+str(userid))
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
duration = default_timer() - start




print the_page
print duration
```

running python gooduser.py in terminal multiple times gives me the fisrt 50 tuples everytime. But when i go to http://0.0.0.0:5000/getEmployees/gooduser on my browser gives me the next 50 entries whenever i refresh it.
How do i get gooduser.py working on the terminal too and get the next 50 entries.

Comment: The browser manages passing the session back to the server for you, `urllib2` isn't going to do that.  Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923296/keeping-a-session-in-python-while-making-http-requests

Comment: thanks man solved my problem