# Python: Use single login for multiple request

Tags: python, session, cookies, urllib2, urllib

There is some random website, http://www.example.com. This website use HTTP basic authentication.

I would like to make multiple requests to this site. But I don't want to login for each of the requests.

I have written the following code:

```
def loginWeb():
    global cookie

    homeURL = "https://www.example.com"
    request = urllib2.Request(homeURL)

    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
    request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   

    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    cookie = response.headers.get('Set-Cookie')
```

The aforementioned code fetches the cookie and uses it for subsequent requests.

The following code makes the subsequent request:

```
def getHTMLSourceCode(ID):        

    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', cookie))

    response = opener.open('https://www.example.com/' + trID)
    sourceCode = response.read()
```

However, `opener.open` throws `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`.

I also tried the following code, but this also throws the same error:

```
def getHTMLSourceCode(trID):        
    request = urllib2.Request("https://www.example.com/" + trID)       
    request.add_header('cookie', cookie)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

    sourceCode = response.read()

    return sourceCode
```

`urllib2.urlopen(request)` throws `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`.

By the way, I went through following answers, but the problem still persists.

[Python urllib2, basic HTTP authentication, and tr.im](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635113/python-urllib2-basic-http-authentication-and-tr-im)

[Keeping a session in python while making HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923296/keeping-a-session-in-python-while-making-http-requests)

[python: urllib2 how to send cookie with urlopen request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334809/python-urllib2-how-to-send-cookie-with-urlopen-request)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `requests` library and use it [Session object](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/)

```
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = (username, password)
s.get(homeURL)
```

The cookie will be set to your session cookie `s.cookies` and you can use this session for other requests.